# React useState sets response from database but when I try to access the data[0].listing_reviews it returns an undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, react-hooks

I need some help understanding why my data can be accessed at index[0] but as soon as I try to access a key on it, it returns an undefined error. The initial state of my data is an empty array. I've confirmed that what I get back from the response is indeed an array of length 1 with an object inside of it.

App.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Reviews from './Reviews.jsx';
import axios from 'axios';

const ReviewsApp = () => {
  const [listingData, setlistingData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 // Random Test ids
    axios
      .get(`listings/${id}/reviews`)
      .then(res => setlistingData(res.data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Reviews listingData={listingData}/>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ReviewsApp;
```

Review.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Reviews = ({ listingData }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(listingData[0].listing_reviews)}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Reviews;
```

So right now, if I console.log(listingData[0]) it works no problem and returns an object with the following structure:

```
listing_id: 0,

listing_rating: 1.5,

listing_reviews: [] <---Full of objects
```

As soon I try to access one of those keys it fails by giving me an undefined error.
Please let me know if you would like some more info as well. Thank you.

Comment: Your `<Reviews>` component is rendering the result of `console.log` which is always undefined. Just remove the wrapping `console.log` from `<Reviews>` (i.e. `{listingData.length ? listingData[0].listing_reviews : null}`) and it should work.

Comment: Its because in your first render `data` is null. Try with this `{listingData.length>0 && <Reviews listingData={listingData}/>}`

Comment: @ShubhamVerma Ah yes of course, that did the trick! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Cully Thank you so much, that actually works too!

Comment: It's the console.log issue. You don't need to conditionally render `<Reviews>`; it will work even if you leave your App.jsx file unchanged. React throws an error if you try to render something that returns undefined, and since console.log always returns undefined, you'll always get an error if you try to render its return value.

Comment: @Cully That's great info, I appreciate that information. I will keep that in mind moving forward. Thank you again.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and explain what the problem was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're rendering the result of `console.log` in your Reviews.jsx file. Anything you put in curly braces `{}` in JSX, React will render. So if you call a function, React will try to render the return value of that function. React throws an error if you try to render `undefined`. And since `console.log` always returns `undefined`, you're always going to get an error. Even if you eventually have data in your `listingData` prop, since you're still trying to render the return of `console.log` and it still returns `undefined`, you'll get an error.

So, just get rid of the `console.log`. Also, you will probably want to check that you actually have data in your `listingData` prop. Otherwise you'll get an error before your data actually loads.

So, something like this for your `Reviews.jsx` file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Reviews = ({ listingData }) => {
  // you can still add a debug line up here. that won't be an issue
  console.log(listingData);

  const reviews = listingData.length ? listingData[0].listing_reviews : null;

  return (
    <div>
      {reviews}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Reviews;
```